# Missig remove option

Tags: google

When I list the attached devices on my Google account in the security option and click to expand the device I wish to remove, then click on the 3 dots in the upper right hand corner, there is no option there to remove the device. Any suggestions as to how I can remove the device.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Previously it was removing access of the google account from the device and now also its doing the same. To remove account access in a specific device, just click on the 3 dots as mentioned above and click sign out.

You can also view your devices from this link https://mydevices.google.com

Comment: That path actually does work, though differently than you intend. It REALLY incentivises you to find the actual path to Google's Security Checkup, of which 'Devices' is a part. Get to Google's Security Checkup here: [https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup](https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup)